# Iozone read command not working

Tags: iozone

Initially when I used `./iozone -a -i 1 -s 2048 -r 2048`, one error came out as

> Can not open temporary file iozone.tmp for read,

any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Are you running `iozone` as root?

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy one.

Usually iozone creates a file in the current directory. So ensure that your user is able to write in the current directory.

Alternatively use: -f /filename  to specify exactly where you want to test.